# Redundancy in power supply

Tags: low-power, redundancy

How is redundancy of power supply from converters done in satellites? can anyone explain with complete details.Is it possible to get the actual design from power system of any mini-satellites ? Is the redundancy of converters actually done?

i want to know how redundancy is maintained for the converter in a satellite.it's the most crucial part as the failure of a converter is highly possible and how is this problem tackled?
by saying converter i mean dc/dc converter

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArduSat